# I need to check 3 things in a 1 do while loop and I am out of ideas

Tags: c#

I am basically building a lottery game, and I need to check several parameters in 1 loop.

I need to check that the user has actually input a number and not something else, I need to check if that number is within the **range of 1 to 47**, and I need to check that the user did not input the same number.

If any of those conditions are not met the user is prompted to repeat himself until all of the conditions are met.

But I am stuck, and I am not really sure how to proceed with the checking of the same number.

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 6; i++)
{
    do
    {
        string input = Console.ReadLine();

        isValidNumber = int.TryParse(input, out valueFromUser);
        isNumberInRange = valueFromUser > 0 && valueFromUser < 47;
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number");
        if (!isNumberInRange)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please input only numbers bigger than 0 and less than 47");

        }
        else if (!isThesame)
        {

        }


    } while(!isValidNumber || !isNumberInRange || !isThesame);

    lucky[i] = valueFromUser;
}

Console.WriteLine("Your chosen numbers are: {0} ,{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5} ", lucky[0], lucky[1], lucky[2], lucky[3], lucky[4], lucky[5]);
```

Comment: Use a `List<int>` for the picks and test using **[List<T>.Contains(T) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.contains?view=netframework-4.8)**

Comment: I am pretty early in my course so unfortunately I did not yet learn what you just wrote.

Comment: If you're stuck on a problem you need to [simplify the problem](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/). First write a loop that accepts any input. Then change the loop to accept only numbers. Then change it to reject numbers less than 1. Then change it to reject numbers less than 1 or over 47. You need to get the first step working before you can advance to the second step. You can see what's going wrong in your program by [using the debugger](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/).

Comment: I did , I got to the point where it rejects letters / anything other than a number and numbers that are bigger than 46 and smaller than 1 , only thing I do not know is how to also make it reject the same numbers.

Comment: `lucky` is an array, not a list, right?

Comment: Yes, it is an array.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most elegant solution. Obviously, the code could be trimmed, just a tad:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int valueFromUser;

            //Method 1
            List<int> lucky = new List<int>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number");

                    if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out valueFromUser))
                    {
                        if (!lucky.Contains(valueFromUser) && (valueFromUser > 0 && valueFromUser < 48))
                        {
                            lucky.Add(valueFromUser); break;
                        }
                    }

                } while (true);
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"Your chosen numbers are: {lucky[0]}, {lucky[1]}, {lucky[2]}, {lucky[3]}, {lucky[4]}"); Console.ReadKey();

            //Method 2

            int[] lucky2 = new int[5];

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number");

                    if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out valueFromUser))
                    {
                        if ((Array.IndexOf(lucky2, valueFromUser) == -1) && (valueFromUser > 0 && valueFromUser < 48))
                        {
                            lucky2[i] = valueFromUser; break;
                        }
                    }

                } while (true);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Your chosen numbers are: {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4} ", lucky2[0], lucky2[1], lucky2[2], lucky2[3], lucky2[4]); Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Array.IndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=netframework-4.8#System_Array_IndexOf_System_Array_System_Object_System_Int32_System_Int32_) method to search for an item in an array. If that item is not found, it will return `-1`. So if this method returns anything other than `-1`, we know that the user has entered the number before.

```
if (i == 0) {
    isThesame = false;
} else if (Array.IndexOf(lucky, valueFromUser, 0, i - 1) != -1) {
    isThesame = true;
}
```

Or simply:

```
isThesame = i != 0 && Array.IndexOf(lucky, valueFromUser, 0, i - 1) != -1;
```

Note that we only search the array up to the element before `lucky[i]`, this is because technically, the rest of the array hasn't been "filled". We don't want to take the initial values at those indices into account.

This also means that we need to handle the special case of `i == 0`. When `i == 0`, `i - 1` will be negative, and passing that to `Array.IndexOf` will throw an exception, which is why we handle it separately.

Comment: I am being throw into an endless loop now, for some reason.

Comment: I updated my answer, to show two different ways.   The second method shows you how to use an int[] and Array.IndexOf().